# How to add a checkbox value using php

Tags: php

I need help with this one. My checkbox value doesnt submit.

```
<input name="helicopter" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $aircraft->helicopter; ?>" checked="<?php
if ($aircraft->helicopter==1) {
                        echo "checked";
                }
?>"/>
```

Comment: what this has to do with `submit`

Comment: Please expand and clarify your question. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please show more code so the problem is clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input name="helicopter" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $aircraft->helicopter; ?>" 
<?php
    if ($aircraft->helicopter==1) {
         echo "checked";
    }
?>>
```